# Firebase Functions OnCreate

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.co = functions.database.ref('/roles')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      var userId = snapshot['userId']
      const doc = admin.database().doc(`/user/${userId}`)

 
      return doc.set(original);
    });
```

Hey everyone,
I want to every time something gets created to '/roles' that it post the value to '/user'.

The value posted to '/roles' has this format:

```
{
 user: userId,
 notification{
   role0: {
       sms: true,
       call: true
      },
   role1: {
       sms: true,
       call: true
      },
 }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a clear use-case. What isn't working about it?

Comment: Are you facing any difficulty or getting any error while doing it? If yes, edit the question and mention it.